# Updating boolean variable depending on changing list

Tags: python

I have a list of user datetime logins of length n, say. Every time the user logs in the list is updated with the new login time.

I want to display a popup every 10 logins, say. What is the best way to do this with the login data with some boolean variable?

Comment: `if len(logins) % 10 == 0: display_popup()`

Comment: When asking a question here, please provide enough code or sample data so that we can replicate on our machines and understand what you are working with. Specify what you are trying to do and any attempt you've made to solve (even if wrong) as well. I would imagine the downvotes are a result of missing those crucial pieces to this question. Please read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You can check whether the length of your list is a multiple of 10, for example.

```py
if len(logins_list) % 10 == 0:
    print("New popup")
```